# Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM PCF Control Error.. Require is not defined

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to build a PCF control based on the below repo

https://github.com/lblod/frontend-embeddable-notule-editor

The usage of this control in any html page has given below

https://jsfiddle.net/0qd27rmg/

So, in my constructor i have loaded the js files required for this control like below

```
constructor()
{
    this.loadScript("https://unpkg.com/svgxuse@1.2.6/svgxuse.js", () => {
    this.loadScript("https://embeddable.gelinkt-notuleren.lblod.info/assets/vendor.js", () => {
    this.loadScript("https://embeddable.gelinkt-notuleren.lblod.info/assets/frontend-embeddable-notule-editor-app.js", () => {
    this.loadScript("https://embeddable.gelinkt-notuleren.lblod.info/assets/frontend-embeddable-notule-editor.js", () => {
        // This callback will be executed when the second script is loaded
        // You can continue to chain additional script loading here
    this.initializeControl();
  });
  });
});
});

loadScript(scriptUrl: string, callback: () => void) {
  const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
  scriptElement.src = scriptUrl;
  scriptElement.onload = callback;
  document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

}

However, when i try to initialize the control in init method like below i am getting the error require is not defined

```
 let App = require('frontend-embeddable-notule-editor/app').default.create({
       autoboot: false,
       name: 'frontend-embeddable-notule-editor'
     });
```

Could you please help me in this control converting to a pcf control

I am expecting if someone help me on how can i use this control or convert this usage to PCF control